# React Native version mismatch. Native 0.54.4 and Javascript 0.52

Tags: android, react-native, expo

After two days of research I hope someone could address me on the right direction.
After upgrading RN version, I'm getting that error when trying to execute on android:
[error on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNls5.png)

I need that version of RN because of library dependencies (I'm able to change RN version up and down), and I'm continuously updating the expo version accordingly on package.json and app.json https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md

BUT I'm not able to update the javascript version. Where it comes from?

Besides that, on iOS is working properly. Any solutions out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed from the [link you shared](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md), native version 0.54.x works with Expo version 26.

The error message is telling you, that you are using a version of React Native that is associated with v25 of Expo. 
If you want to resolve this, make sure your React Native version is 0.54.x and your Expo version is 26.

Alternatively you can also use the branch of React Native that Expo uses:
`json
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-26.0.0.tar.gz"`

And all of this said, the most recent version is 27 so maybe just update all the way :)

If this is a standalone build then please make sure to update it with the latest native modules, as this could be what's causing the platform specific error.

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks for your explanation. I’m starting to think that is related to android studio.

- Using the expo branch as parameter, I can execute properly the app through QR (expo app), but android fails compiling. 
- Using 0.54.4 as parameter, I can execute properly too through expo app, and android compiles correctly, but then it fails with the “react native version mismatch”.

In both cases I’m using the right expo version (26).

Comment: I’ve three components on android (image-picker, maps, and vector-icons). It could be related to that?

Answer (score 0):

I used to met this mismatch before. Because I open a different project without old local dev server closed. So new project run the old server not match.

Try close the server and run your project again.

Comment: the problem follows me for days, even after restarting the computer. at the end it was solve forcing RN to match javascript. not an ideal solution but I didn't find a way

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by Android having a different version of React Native compared to your RN project. You can force Android projects to use a certain version of React Native, by default, the React Native version isn't specified in the Android internal files (the app's build.gradle).

What your app build.gradle most likely looks like right now.

```
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

What you should update your build.gradle to look like

```
compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:<your version of RN here>") {
    force = true
}
```

Example

```
compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.50.4") {
        force = true
    }
```

If you're looking for the app gradle file, it should be located here: `RN-Project/android/app/build.gradle`

These were the steps I took to get it to work. I hope this helps.